# L LED keeps staying on

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, led

I am trying to get the Arduino to reboot my PC when it is off.

Using the front panel header on the PC, I connected the power switch and PLED directly to the Arduino Uno as the header only outputs 5 V.

I'm able to check the status using the L LED, but once I connect the power switch pins to the Arduino to turn on the PC the L LED is always on. This kind of defeats the purpose of what I was trying to do as I wanted the L LED to be off when the PC is off and on when the PC is on, similar to how the LED on the PC power button works.

If someone can give their insight please, the code and pin diagram is below.

```cpp
const int ledPin = 13; // LED on arduino should be on when PC is on and off when PC is off
const int pwrPin = 8; // attached to power switch to turn on and off PC
const int PLED = 7;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // initialize serial communication:
  pinMode(PLED, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwrPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int status;
  status = digitalRead(PLED); // reads the status of PLED
  if (status == HIGH) { // if PC is on keep on until Python script shuts down PC.
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    Serial.print("PC is on");
    delay(5000);
  }
  else { // when PC is off, arduino should turn back on to cold reboot the PC
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial.print("PC is off. Turning on in 10 seconds");
    delay(10000);
    // Added Code. Emulates pushing the PC button when PC is off
    digitalWrite(pwrPin, LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(pwrPin, HIGH);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

[image]

The little box with circles is the front panel header on the mobo.

Comment: what's an L LED?

Comment: @jsotola The Arduino built in LED.

Comment: why is it called `ledPin` in your code?

Comment: what is printed in the serial console? ... please copy and add to your question

Comment: why are you assuming that there is something wrong with the LLED? ... maybe your code is working correctly

Comment: Did I understand right in that the LED correctly showed the status of the PC, until you finally connected the power switch pins to the Arduino? Please clarify. If this is correct: How exactly did you connect everything?

Comment: @chrisl Yes, that is correct. When I disconnect the power switch pins the LED works as intended: ON when the PC is on and OFF when the PC is off. Yet, when I put the power switch pins in, the LED is always turned on. I edited my post to show the pin connections.

Comment: Can you try it again with connecting to the power switch pins, but configuring the pwrpin as INPUT? It won't turn your PC on that way but INPUT makes a pin high impedance (electric equivalent of an unconnected pin) and I want to check if that changes something (and maybe find something about the core problem)

Comment: @chrisl I've tried that before, but I just took another crack at it and same thing happened. Separately, I have tried running just the code to turn on the PC on another file and I found that setting the pwrpin to OUTPUT works , but INPUT does not. Which is why I set pwrpin as OUTPUT in my main code. Hope this information is useful.

Comment: @chrisl Also, I don't know if this will help or if you already know this but the pwr switch outputs 5v at anytime even when the PC is off. When I turn off the PSU, the pwr switch has no voltage and the built-in LED turns off.

Comment: @Ant, the power switch is connected between ground and power-on signal line ... the power-on signal is most likely pulled towards 5 V with a pullup resistor ... the switch pulls it to ground when the switch is pressed

Comment: Did you check the circuit internal to the motherboard, how the LED is controlled? Chances are that "PLED-" is switched, not "PLED+", so that connecting "PLED-" to GND as you did will make it on all the time. Measure the pins on the PC's header, for example.

Comment: @thebusybee I know that when the PC is on PLED is measured at 5v and 0v when the PC is off. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @jsotola would that be a potential cause for the built-in LED to be always on?

Comment: Hm, which of both PLED pins do you mean? -- What do you measure at "PLED-" if the PC is on, what if the PC is off, and what do you measure at "PLED+" the same time? Do _not_ connect the Arduino and use "GND" as reference. Please add these four values to your question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score -1):

The led power pins on the motherboard you are connecting to are not "power led+" and "power led-", they are "led+" for two separate leds (specifically meant for a green led and a yellow led). See [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005643/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) for the pinout used by Intel.

All the leds use the a common ground for "led-". By connecting it as you have, you are shorting out one of the led pins. Disconnect that pin from ground and you should be able to read the other pin correctly.